# Sorting of alphanumeric values in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, phpexcel

I use PHPExcel to export some data to Excel.

I initially sort the list of alphanumeric characters in PHP exactly as I want it (see below to the left).

But when exported to Excel our customers want to use Excel's sorting to sort the data, which results in the sorting seen below to the right (Alphabetically, A-Z)

Is there any way we can work around this? Perhaps using a formula to display one value in the cell, but give the cell a different value (for sorting)?

Or a custom cell format?

As a last resort I plan on introducing a ID column in the beginning so one can always return to the initial sort by sorting the ID column, but I'd rather not use this solution, if possible.

```
Initial Sort        Excel Sort
2586                2586
2587                2587
2587-1              2590
2587-2              2592
2590                2595
2590-1              2587-1
2590-2              2587-2
2590-3              2590-1
2590-4              2590-10
2590-5              2590-11
2590-6              2590-2
2590-7              2590-3
2590-8              2590-4
2590-9              2590-5
2590-10             2590-6
2590-11             2590-7
2592                2590-8
2595                2590-9
```

Comment: When you import, import as text.  Excel puts numbers first when sorting, then make sure when they sort they do not choose the sort by values the look like numbers as numbers.

Comment: On the right seems to be alphabetical sorting.

Comment: What about just defining an autofilter range, then the users have the toolbar in the headings row to sort themselves

Answer (score 0):

If you place an apostrophe in front of each line it sorts as follows:

```
2586
2587
2587-1
2587-2
2590
2590-1
2590-10
2590-11
2590-2
2590-3
2590-4
2590-5
2590-6
2590-7
2590-8
2590-9
2592
2595
```

which is what you want, right?

Comment: No, I want it as it is initially sorted (as seen in my list to the left). Added that to the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Excel will sort according to its own rules, and formatting will not change a thing.  You can sort on different columns than the ID column; those columns could be hidden and the sort triggered by a button; or some other way to make it easy for your end-users.

Below is an example of one way of doing things:

You can set up two helper columns, representing the left and right parts of the ID as numbers.

With your IDs in Column B:

```
C2: =--(LEFT(B2,FIND("-",B2&"-")-1))
D2: =IFERROR(--MID(B2,FIND("-",B2)+1,99),0)
```

and fill down.

Because of the manner in which Excel sorts blanks, you need to place a zero in the fields of the second part which might be blank

Then select the table, and sort on Column C, then on Column D.

When finished, delete or hide columns C:D

## Before Sort

[image]

## Sort Dialog

[image]

## After Sort

[image]